# Crontab + rails3 + bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, bundler

I'm running a crontab that executes a rake task. I'm getting the following error (with MAILTO from crontab):

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- bundler
/Users/Mendel/Sites/misnooit/Rakefile:4
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm using rvm with:
ruby: ruby 1.9.1p378 
rails: Rails 3.0.0.beta
$GEM_HOME: /Users/Mendel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378
bundler: bundler (0.9.11)

The error is pretty self explanatory but I'm not able to fix it.. Is there someone with more knowledge about this matter? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you sure that your user load your rvm configuration ?

Comment: I think I am, but can you show me how you would do it? Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 6):

I just experienced this.  Problem for me was that the instances of rake and ruby I use were built locally, and installed to /usr/local/bin.  There are other versions in /usr/bin (must check what I installed using apt-get in the past..).

So, in my crontab file I set the path using

PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

(I was seeing it as PATH=/usr/bin:/bin in the failed crontab emails)

and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing: is `Ruby 1.9.1p378` your default Ruby?

I think it's not so you can just execute `rvm --defaults "ruby-1.9.1-p378"`
If this doesn't help, are you sure bundler has been installed when ruby 1.9 was used?

Also, in your test/production environment, you may want to run you cron with another user than yourself. So I suggest you install rvm as "root", and set up (still as root) a default RVM that will be the default for all the system users.
And of course, you can override this per user.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good experience using http://github.com/javan/whenever

It uses a Ruby DSL to manage cron tasks and it handles setting all the environment magic.

```
every 3.hours do
  runner "MyModel.some_process"
  rake "my:rake:task"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

have your run the command with --trace asserted to ensure there isn't something obvious in the rake command, but what you could do is chain the crontab commands

```
rvm 1.9.1;rake do_whatever_task
```

That way it will load the ruby environment every time prior to running rake.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue this weekend, I found that my Rake Gem was updated to 0.90 you need rake 0.8.7. This solved the issue on my end.